# how to post a two dimensial JSON array to a webservice

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, json

I want to POST a 2d array from my json code to my webservice,
my array looks like this: {"portlets":["portlet2","portlet3","portlet1","portlet4"],"columns":["column1","column1","column2","column2"]}

and what i want to do in my webservice is to get witch portlet is in witch column and what sortindex it has, for example:

- portlet1 is in column1 and has sortindex 0
- portlet2 is in column1 and has sortindex 1
- portlet3 is in column2 and has sortindex 0
- portlet4 is in column2 and has sortindex 1

this is my json code so far:

```
function SavePositions() {

    var pid = $('.portlet').map(function () { return this.id; }).get();
    var colid = $('.portlet').map(function () { return $("#" + this.id).parent().attr('id').replace("MainContent_", ""); }).get();
    var jsonText = JSON.stringify({ portlets: pid, columns: colid });

            $.ajax({

                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: jsonText,
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                url: "PortletWeb.asmx/SavePortletPositions"

            })

}
```

i started out with just some codelines to see if it works but i get an error :

"NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://localhost:60651/PortletWeb.asmx/SavePortletPositions"

This is my Webservice code:

```
[WebMethod]
    public void SavePortletPositions(string[,] portlets)
    {  }
```

Comment: should i use a string parameter instead of a 2d string array, in that case how do i deal with the 2d array data i get from the Json post in my webservice?

Comment: Do the two things correlate so that portlet would be portletId and a columnId? or are they unrelated?

Comment: they are related, for example; portlet1 is inside of column1

Comment: Take a look at my answer on this question regarding the Phone block to see if that might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780781/how-do-i-do-a-list-of-items-in-jquery-and-get-it-on-server-side/2781373#2781373  - basically define a portlet object with strings portletId and columnId and create a portlet object on the server to reflect that object, accept an array of portlets in your web method.

Comment: bit old but have you tried a jagged array? string[][]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

c# code:

```
   public class portlets
        {
            public Portlet()
            {
                PrortletId= "";
                ColumnId= "";
            }
            public String PortletId{ get; set; }
            public String ColumnId { get; set; }
        }


    [WebMethod]
    public void SavePortletPositions(Portlet[] portlet)
    {
    // do what you need with the object
    }
```

JS code:

```
function jsonObject() { };
var portletListObject = new jsonObject(); 
function SaveJsonObject() {
     portletListObject = new jsonObject();
     portletListObject.Portlet = new Array();
     $('.portlet').each(function(myindex)
     {
         portletListObject.Portlet[myindex].PortletId = this.id;
         portletListObject.Portlet[myindex].ColumnId = $("#" + this.id).parent().attr('id').replace("MainContent_", ""); 
      });
};
 function SavePositions() {
      SaveJsonObject()
      var jsonText = JSON.stringify('{ "portlets":'JSON.stringify(portletListObject)+'}');
              $.ajax({
                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                 data: jsonText,
                 type: "POST",
                 dataType: "json",
                 url: "PortletWeb.asmx/SavePortletPositions"
              })
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually ive found another approach, 
first of all i made a function that gets the sortindex of my portlets:

```
function getSortIndex(columnid, portletid) {
    var portlets = [];
    $("#" + $("#" + portletid).parent().attr('id')).children().each(function () {
        portlets.push($(this).attr('id'));
    });
    for (var i = 0; i < $("#" + $("#" + portletid).parent().attr('id')).children().length; i++) {
        if (portlets[i] == portletid) {

            return i;
        }
    }
}
```

for example if i write get getSortIndex(portlet2) it will return me the sortindex of portlet2, in this case the sortindex of portlet2 is 0.

on this next stage i create an array of objects, and each object has 3 properties, in this case those 3 is: portletid, columnid and sortindex.

```
    function SavePositions() {
    var jsonstring = "";
    var portlets = [];

    $('.portlet').each(function () {
        var portlet = new Object();
        portlet.portletid = $(this).attr('id');
        portlet.columnid = $(this).parent().attr('id').replace("MainContent_", "");
        portlet.sortindex = getSortIndex(portlet.columnid, portlet.portletid);
        portlets.push(portlet);
    });
    jsonstring = JSON.stringify(portlets);
    console.log(jsonstring);
    $.ajax({
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: "{'json':'" + jsonstring + "'}",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "PortletWeb.asmx/SavePortletPositions",
        success: function () { },
        error: function () { alert('error'); }
    })
}
```

i also use .push() to store each object into my array
and after i JSON.stringify my array of objects i get:

```
[{"portletid":"portlet2","columnid":"column1","sortindex":0},
{"portletid":"portlet3","columnid":"column1","sortindex":1},
{"portletid":"portlet1","columnid":"column2","sortindex":0},
{"portletid":"portlet4","columnid":"column2","sortindex":1}]
```

and in my webmethod:

```
 [WebMethod]
    public void SavePortletPositions(string json)
    {
        JObject portlet = JObject.Parse(json); }
```

the only plroblem is in my webmethod i use JSON.Net and try to parse my json string all i get is:

"Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: StartArray"

have i missed something?

Answer (score 0):

In controller you must receive it as IEnumerable or two strings, and write method filter 
**[HttpPost]**

```
  [HttpPost]
  public void SavePortletPositions(IEnumerable<string> portlets, IEnumerable<string> columns)
  {  

  }
```

or

```
  [HttpPost]
  public void SavePortletPositions(string portlets, string columns)
  {  
        List<string> lColumns  = columns.Split(',').ToList();
        List<string> lPortlets = portlets.Split(',').ToList();
  }
```